# Schedule bash script on windows task

Tags: windows, bash, sh

I am trying to schedule a sh script to run using windows task but i can't get the right syntax, i'm hoping someone can help.

I have setup my action "start a program" with:

```
- Program/script: "C:\Program Files (x86)\cygwin\bin\bash.exe"
- Add arguments: -l -c "/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9/.../script.sh"
- Start script: nothing
```

I am not getting any error the task is completed when i run it but i can see that my script sh did not run. I'm pretty sure i'm missing something stupid in the syntax but can't find it...

Thanks!

Comment: May be it has to do with spaces in your directory names. Did you try escaping them with a \ ?

Comment: `...`? What is that supposed to represent? It's not valid in any sort of relative path. Do you really have a directory named `...` in your `EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You've got three dots in the middle of the path, that may be it.